# Method must be called from main thread,currenty inferred thread is worker

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I am trying to change the wallpaper of Android every 15 minutes or something like this. A user can choose the time and I am running a periodic work using Workmanager.

```
PeriodicWorkRequest periodicWorkRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(SomeWorker.class, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build();
WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(periodicWorkRequest);
```

This way I am calling my Worker Class. The working class is this

```
public class SomeWorker extends Worker {
Context context = getApplicationContext();
private String URL;
@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {
    new FetchWallpaper().execute();
    return Result.SUCCESS;
}
private class FetchWallpaper extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try
        {
            URL = "myurl.com";
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(URL)
                    .build();
            Response responses = null;
            try {
                responses = client
                        .newCall(request)
                        .execute();
                String jsonData = responses.body().string();

                JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(jsonData);
                JSONObject c = jsonArr.getJSONObject(new Random().nextInt(jsonArr.length()));

                String imageUrl = c.getString("wallpaper");

                Bitmap result= Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                        .load(imageUrl)
                        .get();

                WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                try {
                    wallpaperManager.setBitmap(result);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        }
        return null;
    }
}}
```

On that Particular line,

```
        new FetchWallpaper().execute();
```

I am getting the error saying it must call from the main thread. I am new to Android, I don't know if this is the good approach.
Please let me know if there is any better approach to perform such kind of task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Worker` class already calls `doWork` on a background thread - you don't need to use `AsyncTask` at all.

Just move everything from your `doInBackground` method directly into the Worker's `doWork`.

Answer (score 0):

You can not update UI from `doInBackground` method. If you want to do something on UI you must do that on Main UI thread. So write `setBitmap` code in `onPostExecute` method as `onPostExecute` on on Main UI Thread.

To do that set third parameter of AsyncTask as `String`

```
AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
```

So that return type of `doInBackground` method will be `String`

```
protected String doInBackground(Void... voids)
...
...
return imageUrl;
}
```

And Your onPostExecute method will be like

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String imageUrl) {
    super.onPostExecute(imageUrl);

 Bitmap result= Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                    .load(imageUrl)
                    .get();

 WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
 try {
        wallpaperManager.setBitmap(result);
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }

}
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but it changes the wallpaper as long as the app is running, as soon as I close the app, the work manager works, but doesn't update the wallpaper.

Comment: That is not related with this question. This answer is related to stop throwing exception. For that you can ask another question.

Comment: If this answer helps you to solve exception then you can accept it as write answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Bitmap, Bitmap>() {
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
       Bitmap bitmap = null;
       try {
           InputStream inputStream;
           inputStream = new java.net.URL(url).openStream();
           bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
        }catch (Exception e) {
           logAppE(TAG, "BITMAP ERROR -> " + e.getMessage());
         }
         return bitmap
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap s) {
        try {
            Glide.with(context).asGif().load(s).into(imgViewGIF);
        } catch (Exception e) {
              logAppE(TAG, "BITMAP -> " + e.getMessage());
         }
      }
    }.execute();
```